# Escaping backslash In elisp

Tags: string, escaping, elisp

I am trying to create the string `\]` in elisp for inclusion in a regular expression. When I return the string `\\]` I get the string `\\]`, but when I return the string `\]` I get the string `]`. This doesn't really make any sense to me. Here is output from the ielm:

```
ELISP> "\\"
"\\"
ELISP> "\\]"
"\\]"
ELISP> "\]"
"]"
```

What is going on here. Why isn't the first backslash escaping the second one?

Comment: Don't understand the question. There's only one backslash in the last example, which is "the second one"?

Answer (score 9):

What you're missing is that strings print the same way you have to type them. So if a string contains a character that requires escaping, a backslash will be printed before it. But if it contains a character that doesn't require escaping, there won't be one printed.

When you type `"\\"`, it creates a string containing a single backslash character. This gets printed as `"\\"`.

When you type `"\\["`, it creates a string containing two characters: backslash followed by square bracket. This gets printed as `"\\["`.

When you type `"\["`, the backslash escapes the square bracket. This escaping is redundant, since square brackets don't need to be escaped. So it creates the same string as `"["`: a string containing the single square bracket character. This gets printed as `"["`, because there's no need to escape square brackets.

Comment: I would add this: see `(elisp) Syntax for Strings` (in the Emacs Lisp manual, use `g Syntax for  Strings`). Always remember: in Lisp strings, double the number of backslashes you want.